# How to install the mono-develop IDE for mono 3.0.2 on Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS 64?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, mono-framework, monodevelop

I've downloaded (from the mono-project.com web site) and installed mono 3.0.2 for a specific purpose in /usr/lib on my Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS 64 bit system using these commands:

```
wget -O Downloads/mono-3.0.2.tar.bz2 http://origin-download.mono-project.com/sources/mono/mono-3.0.2.tar.bz2 
tar -C Downloads -xjf Downloads/mono-3.0.2.tar.bz2
cd Downloads/mono-3.0.2
sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr
sudo make
sudo make install
```

Now, I'd like to install the mono-develop IDE, but I'm scared to use apt-get or synaptic since the Ubuntu standard installation install an old version of mono and furthermore doesn't install the shared libraries into /usr/lib.

Any help to install this IDE (or another one) supporting mono 3.0.2 will be very appreciated.

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that monodevelop has a lot of dependencies that you will need to install manually (as in, without packages, like you did with Mono), such as:

- gtk-sharp (the 2-12 branch)
- gnome-sharp
- mono-addins

And some other that maybe I'm forgetting.

If you really want to live on the edge but without suffering so much pain, you should, first, stop using a LTS distro (install 12.10 for example), and then grab preview mono 3.0 packages from here: http://www.meebey.net/posts/mono_3.0_preview_debian_ubuntu_packages/

This way you will still be able to use the packaging system for installing dependencies like the ones listed above, and then you can clone monodevelop from github and use the latest version without problems.

Another option, in case you don't want to upgrade your distro, is that you install mono 3.0 in parallel with the mono 2.x that comes with the distro. To be able to do this you need to have special care: have a good read of [this guide](http://www.mono-project.com/Parallel_Mono_Environments).

Answer (score 0):

Hi knocte and thank you very much for all the precisions.

Meanwhile, I can't move right now to the 12.10 and I definitely need to get monodevelop working on the 12.04 LTS with my current mono installation.

However, I'll test your proposal with a 12.10 later in a VM.

Further, I didn't install mono using my distro install because as I said:

a) the one that's proposed by Ubuntu 12.04.2 is an old 2.x,

b) I need specifically to use a 3.0.x version for my tests,

c) and I need to install it into /usr/lib for a specific project that dynamically binds mono libraries if and only if they're located into /usr/lib (and there is no way to make changes of that specific behavior, at least for now).

BTW, the install of my current mono 3.0.2 was very easy (but only took a very long time - LoL) and works fine with the specific project I'm testing on.

So, is there a place where I can find the different steps to follow in order to install the IDE monodevelop that would use my current installation into /usr/lib without deleting my current mono 3.0.2 installation?

The other way to use a parallel installation such as promoted there : http://www.mono-project.com/Parallel_Mono_Environments isn't either a way I could use with the specific project I'm testing.

Or is there another IDE (such as Eclipse or Code::blocks) that supports Mono on Linux?

TIA.